# Will users need special runtime files if I use SQL & LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, sql, file, linq-to-entities, runtime

I am currently using xml files to store large amounts of data which are serialized and deserialized to and from the files into instances of a data model class. I would like to change this to SQL for obvious performance reasons. So I am thinking something along the lines of a Local Database (.sdf - SQL Server Compact Edition Database File).

My question is if I use this will the consumers of my program need some special runtimes installed or even an SQL product?

Thanks in advance.

PS I am writing in C# & WPF

Comment: an update to my query: compact 4 makes deployment easier you just need to copy the DLLs to your app folder (and something similar for asp) - see sql ce 4 release notes for more detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They will need the .NET 4.0 Full Framework (not Client Profile), and you would also need to distribute the SQLCE DLLs with your application (not hard to do, only ~4 small DLLs).